# How to keep specific columns within a 2D array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a code that collects info on a sheet :

```
function REPART_HEURES_004() {


  var LISTE_PROJsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_LISTE PROJETS");


  var LISTE_PROJStartRow = 5;
  var lrLISTE_PROJ = LISTE_PROJsheet.getLastRow()+1;
  var rangeLISTE_PROJ = LISTE_PROJsheet.getRange(LISTE_PROJStartRow,1,lrLISTE_PROJ-LISTE_PROJStartRow,15);
  var LISTE_PROJ = rangeLISTE_PROJ.getValues();

  Logger.log(LISTE_PROJ)

}
```

it's perfectly working

the `Logger.log(LISTE_PROJ)` give me such a result :

```
[[DE, SMNK_KARLSRUHE, true, Scénographie, Design et production exposition, kikou, , , , , , , , false, ],
[DE, KASSBERG, true, Maquette tactile bâtiment, 1 maquette tricolore en exté, , , , , , , , , false, ],
[FR, ARROMANCHES, true, Maquette pure / objet non inclusif, 1 maquette 7 m de long, , , , , , , , , true, ]
[DE, DHM BERLIN, true, Plan tactile, 2 plans tactiles, , , , , , , , , true, ],
[FR, CHARTREUSE AVIGNON, true, Maquette tactile bâtiment, ........
```

The problem is that in these values, I only need columns `[ 2, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]`.

so for the first row, the result I need should look like that :

```
[SMNK_KARLSRUHE, kikou, , , , false, ]
```

I have found many different answers to this type of question... But no one that I can figure out and adapt to what probably is a simple question...
I have also try to find some result with "delete column on a 2D array" but it wasn't really successfull.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Try learning how to use the map method of arrays

Comment: more them an advice !

Answer (score 2):

thanks to Cooper, I went on youtube and copy the exact advice it gave me :
"learning how to use the map method of arrays" on the reseach bar, and with a bit of luck, I found that :

```
  var data = LISTE_PROJ
  var newdata = data.map(function(row){return [row[2],row[5],row[7],row[9],row[11],row[13]]})
  Logger.log(newdata)
```

which have allow me to retrieve only the column I wanted on my `LISTE_PROJ`

Comment: You may also translate your `map` with [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in your map like `data.map(row => [row[2],row[5],row[7],row[9],row[11],row[13]])`.

Comment: let output = data.map(([a,b,c,d,e,f,g]) => [b,c,d,e]);

Comment: you might consider changing the syntax as you're actually checking the `col` not row just for clarity.

Comment: Also, your numbering in your answer is off. I'm not sure which columns you're using (i.e. base zero for arrays or base 1 for how Sheets labels columns), but it looks inconsist in your answer compared to your original question of `[2,6,...`

Comment: @pgSystemTester `row` is the most accurate variable name. `data` consists of ` rows` and rows consist of `col` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, if you're trying to get this data to be used within Google Sheets, you don't need to use app scripts thanks to newer formulas such as [ChooseCol](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914?hl=en).

Specifically, if your initial range is A5:Z (last row extended to column z), the following formula would return a dynamic list of on the columns you wanted:

`=CHOOSECOLS(filter(A5:Z,A5:A<>""),2,6,8,10,12,14)`

Comment: thanks, but it really have to be in a script !

Comment: I figured, I'll leave the answer up just in case someone else finds useful in similar situation.